# Warranty on products received as a giveaway

Tags: ipad, warranty

I received an ipad mini 2 months ago as a giveaway at a computer company luncheon.  It is my 4th ipad & 1st mini.  Two nights ago, I noticed the back right side (left side if looking at the back) was hot and the device was not responsive.  Charging or resetting using the dual-button process made no difference in status.  I was wondering if anyone knows if a device "won" new at a computer show or luncheon is still covered by warranty?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Your mini should be covered under warranty since they haven't been out for a full year yet, however you can double check using Apple's public facing service site - [SelfSolve.Apple.com](https://selfsolve.apple.com/)

Apple's warranty follows the device by it's serial number, not the owner, so winning it through a raffle shouldn't have any effect other than it may have been purchased weeks/months before it reached your hands.